How to Properly Read a Static File in SvelteKit Using a Server-Side Load Function?
I am working on a SvelteKit project where I want to dynamically render HTML content based on a route parameter (e.g., /2023, /2022). I have static HTML files (2012.html, 2013.html, etc.) stored in the src/assets directory, and I'm trying to read them in the +page.server.ts file using the fetch API.

What I Am Trying to Achieve
For each route like /2023 or /2022, I want to dynamically load an HTML file corresponding to the year from the server and render it on the page. For example, navigating to /2023 should fetch 2023.html from the src/assets or any folder and display its content. I just would like to avoid using static/ folder because I dont want to expose html like that and i do want users to visit proper svelte page.
My Setup
Here is my server-side load function in +page.server.ts:
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ params, fetch }) => {
  try {
    // Use fetch to get the HTML content from the server
    console.log(params.year) //works e.g."2012"
    const {year} = params
    const response = await fetch(`src/assets/${year}.html`); // what is the proper method to get file?

    // Check if the response is OK (status 200-299)
    if (!response.ok) {
      console.error(`Error fetching the HTML file: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
      return { dom: { html: '' } };
    }

    // Read the response as text
    const html = await response.text();

    // Log the HTML content for debugging
    console.log('HTML content:', html);

    return {
      dom: { html },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error reading the HTML file:', error);
    return {
      dom: { html: '' }, // Return empty string on any error
    };
  }
};

And my corresponding Svelte page component +page.svelte looks like this:
<script lang="ts">
  import type { PageData } from './$types';

  export let data: PageData;
</script>

<pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>

The Problem
When I try to access any of the routes, I consistently get a 500 Internal Server Error. Here are the logs I receive on each reload:
Error fetching the HTML file: 500 Internal Server Error
Error fetching the HTML file: 500 Internal Server Error
2:28:49 AM [vite] page reload src/routes/[year]/+page.server.ts
Error fetching the HTML file: 500 Internal Server Error


Files can be dynamically imported. For certain file types there already is a handler, e.g. images are imported as URLs to an asset, but there also are query params to instruct Vite how to import.
Here you could just import the contents directly using ?raw like this:
const file = await import(`../../assets/${year}.html?raw`)
    .then(m => m.default);

(Not sure if aliases can be used, tried using $lib and that did not seem to work.)
If you make the route just a standalone +server.ts endpoint (no +page.svelte), you can return the contents using text:
// routes/[year]/+server.ts
import { text, type RequestHandler } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const GET = (async ({ params }) => {
    const file = await import(`../../assets/${params.year}.html?raw`)
        .then(m => m.default);

    return text(file, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        },
    });
}) satisfies RequestHandler;

As pointed out by Peppe L-G, the ?raw import transforms the contents to a string in JS, which has some overhead and prevents more direct streaming to the client. An alternative might be using an ?url import in combination with read which should be equivalent to Peppe's answer.
If you don't transform the HTML or add other route-specific logic, you might as well use the static directory instead.

✅ Wow thank you so much! i learned relation between import and proper caching. Now everything works as i wanted; files are coming from assets/!

If I'm not mistaking, there are two big downsides with this solution: (1) ?raw imports the entire file content as a string, while read() on the other hand will just pass around a buffer, which consumes less memory and is faster, and (2) Vite will replace ?raw imports with strings in the code containing the file contents, so your app code will be bigger, including consuming more memory to run, even when it's not processing requests for these HTML the files. But if the HTML files are small and few, then no big problem.

And I still don't understand why one would want to do it like this instead of using the static folder. It's a very complicated way of doing the same thing? But if @kawa is happy, then no problem ^^

@PeppeL-G: Correct regarding the downsides, using ?url and read might work as an alternative (or as you suggested changing the assets list in the config).

@PeppeL-G: If you don't transform the HTML in code, there is little point in using a route and you really might as well use static. Better handling of the not-found case might also be an aspect.

@PeppeL-G The main reason is that i want to load ads load on the page from +layout.svelte instead of letting people have option to view .html files. Also. if i decided to use different files such as .json for cheap api, this would prevent exposing such important files. for those reasons, i wanted use assets/ folder

I'm not sure if this will work, but it's a too long answer to suggest as a comment, so I write it as an answer. I hope it will work ^^'

In vite.config.js, configure assetsInclude to include HTML files
In your +page.server.ts file:

Import all of your HTML files (doesn't matter where in your project you place the HTML files, thanks to (1))
In the load() function, use read() to send back the HTML file you want that you imported
I'm guessing you also need to set the Content-Type header in the response to text/html



The links that leads to these routes probably also needs to include target="_self", so SvelteKit doesn't try to load them as ordinary routes, but does a full page load.
read() in SvelteKit is quite poorly documented IMO, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4G-6dyF1MU&t=67s to learn more about it.

HOWEVER, this is just a very complicated way of doing:

I just would like to avoid using static/ folder because I dont want to expose html like that and i do want users to visit proper svelte page.

So I'm not sure why you really would prefer doing it like this :/

✅ After youe suggeston, i figured that it is not  that easy to do what i initially wanted, so  I decided to move filess to static/ folder as it is way more straightfoward.
Changed to → const response = await fetch(${year}.html);Thanks for advice!

@kawa: Would not recommend using static, unless you do manual cache busting, you may run into issues when you ever change these files.

@kawa: Actually, I think that might have been an issue in the past or i'm just misremembering; currently there are no headers on files in static that would allow caching. So it's more the other way around, you don't cache too much but too little. In any case, if you want to support proper caching, import the assets.
